# Is there still documentation or support for https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to find more information, but I cannot get access to the API portal page https://www.projectoxford.ai/vision . Do you know if Microsoft is planning to remove the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProjectOxford was deprecated in favor of [Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/#api)

The Vision API have the following main paths

[**Computer Vision**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)

> Analyze content in images and video.

[**Custom Vision**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/)

> Customize image recognition to fit your business needs.

[**Face**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/)

> Detect and identify people and emotions in images.

[**Form Recognizer**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/)

> Extract text, key-value pairs, and tables from documents.

[**Video Indexer**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/video-indexer/)

> Analyze the visual and audio channels of a video, and index its content.

DEV API reference of all services ➡ https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/

Comment: I see, I use this API in my code, with processes after that. I am guessing that replace it for the new cognitive service will take me a while. Do you know, when are you planning to remove completely api.projectoxford.ai?

Comment: @Ber I don’t know, I’m not a Microsoft employee but did you check the link to API reference on my answer? I guess maybe is not as hard to change the API. Look at this endpoints especially 1.0 version (oldest) https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services?pattern=Vision Don’t forget mark as accepted if it answer your question.